# Azure AD App Authentication Successfully Authenticating all Apps in Same Tenant Without Delegation/White-listed Permission

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I am using Azure AD app to app authentication and also user authentication.
Now, from within the same AD tenant any registered app is able to call my app with both user or app token even though I have not added/white-listed the caller app. This is in contrast to what use to happen couple of years back where we had to add delegated permission in our app registration permissions to allow any app to call us with a token.

My Asp.Net Core App is using below code snippet to setup authentication.

```
services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
            {
                sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer((option) =>
            {
                option.Audience = audience;
                option.Authority = authority;
                option.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                };
            });
```

Please let me know why there is no need to add delegated permission in Azure AD app anymore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have hit one of the features of Azure AD.
An app in any tenant can acquire an access token for an API in any tenant as long as they know its identifiers (tenant id + client id/app id URI).
The token will not contain any delegated permissions or application permissions, there is no way for it to get those without requiring them + someone consenting them of course.
But it will be otherwise valid.

You need to check in your API that the caller has appropriate permissions to call your API.
Check that the token contains a valid delegated permission or application permission.
Delegated permissions will be space-delimited in the scp claim, and application permissions will be in an array in the roles claim.
Failing to do these checks can leave your API vulnerable.

Comment: Thanks for the response Juunas, is this feature newly launched, earlier by default token use to fail without delegation permission. Also, can you please point me to some official documentation on this topic.

Comment: I haven't seen official docs on this and I don't think behaviour has changed. This is all based on my observations.

Comment: Be sure to check for valid permissions, and you'll be good :)

Comment: Just to be clear, when you say “an app in any tenant can acquire an access token for an api in any tenant” this all can only be in the *same* tenant right!!?

Comment: Nope, an app in another tenant can use client credentials to get a token for an API in your tenant. It won't contain permissions of course. This is why checking for permissions is really important. I've told the MS identity team about this and they are aware of it.